Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS freezes when copying larger amount of data from USB to hard disc
I found out some problems copying larger amount of files from USB hard drive.
For example copying my Documents, which is 13.035 files, in total size of 21,2GB.
It started to copy, but after a while the whole system had frozen. When frozen, I was not able to move with mouse, or do anything. Even CTRL+ALT+PRT SC+REISUB for software reset hasn't worked, so I had to perform hard reset with power button. I had to repeat about 3 or 4 times, to be able to copy the whole Document folder. I dont't remember, this would happen on Ubuntu 22.04. I have tryied 2 different PC's and 2 different USB hard drives and different folders (Documets, Photos, Thunderbird or Firefox profile files). This happened at least 1 time with every combination.
PC'S i have tryied:

Lenovo Ideapad 320-15ABR with 960GB SSD disc, 20GB RAM, 9GB Swap File
HP notebook with 1TB SSD disc, 8GB RAM, 15GB Swap file

USB hard drives I have tryied:

1TB Verbatim USB disc
1TB WD Element USB disc

I have found similar questions on the forum:

large data transfer troubles with ubuntu 24.04
Status: unanswered
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Freeze when data transfer
This one was resolved after deleting all the __pycache__directories, but I dont have any code files, I copy just documents or photos and it happens anyway.


I use Kubuntu and external SSD, so have had no issues. What format is external drive? Is external drive USB powered or has external power? My first USB adapter with only USB power worked for SSD, but would not even spin up HDD.

It is USB powered and format is NTFS. But as I said I haven't had problems with the same hardware on the Ubuntu 22.04
